# Classifying type of crop on satellite images using Python

Tags: python, sentinel-2, land-classification, change-detection

I'm trying to make a classification on the send with python, but logically I find all the vegetation that I don't care about. The even more serious fact is that if the species is not present in a homogeneous way it is difficult to use even the send.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Dzetaska classification tool.
Seems to work pretty good.  > 80% 
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/dzetsaka/

I have been using it on QGIS.  I do not know anything about python.
Step one-Draw polygon over each object class.
[image]

Step 2 run classifier:
[image]

This produces classified image:
[image]

Comment: can I import it on python?

Comment: Could you please include more details such as a summary or a URL?